# How to convert a object string into an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a JavaScript string into a workable JavaScript object without using the eval().
For example, convert a string like this:

`beforeMagic="{{height: { type: String, default: \"auto\", realType: \"cssHeight\", required: false }, title: { type: String, required: true}}"`

to

afterMagic= {
height: {
type: String,
default: "auto",
realType: "cssHeight",
required: false
},
title: {
type: String,
required: true
}
}

Comment: Where does the string come from? If there’s an option to make it valid JSON, then parsing it as JSON is trivial. How is the `type` property used?

Comment: What is `type: String` supposed to mean? `String` is not a valid literal, it would need to be quoted.

Comment: Without quotes, it's a variable (it's the built-in String class). Do you want the value of the variable put into the object?

Comment: You can use `eval()` to parse it, but this is dangerous if the source is not trusted.

Comment: The short answer, ignoring invalid input (`{{` and `}}`), and overlooking the unquoted text, is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Deserialize a JSON into a JavaScript object, here you can use a common method JSON.parse() method.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(your-string);
```

Comment: The problem of using this is that the string is not correctly formatted for using JSON.parse().

Comment: I can't parse it since there are no double quotes around the object property

Comment: Then I think you should manipulate string before convert into an object, so please use some string operations to make it familiar for JSON.parse.